# How to initialise a JmsListener in spring boot based on a flag getting set at app startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

Need to initialise a listener only if it required to, based on a flag which is set at app startup from external source and not from application.properties.

```
class PropertyClass {
      boolean flag;
..
getters 
setters
..

}

@Configuration
class classSettingProperties () {

    @Bean 
    public  PropertyClass propertyClass() {
         PropertyClass propertyClass = new PropertClass () ;

         propertyClass.setflag(true or false);
         // Just an example how this property is set.

         return propertyClass; 

    }
}

@Component
public class ListenerClass {

    @JmsListener (... destination and factory details)
    public void listenerMethod () {
    .
    .
    .
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the listener container factory `autoStartup` property to true(default) or false, according to your desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the solution i will try it. Till now i used JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar and registered the listener only if flag is on. What difference will it make in the 2 approches other then little extra code in the second approach.

Comment: There is not really much difference.